# Initialize static class atributes in python

Tags: python, class, static-variables

I have the following class

```py
class Test:
    x = None  # this is a static variable common to all object created from this class

    @classmethod
    def initializeX(cls):
        cls.x = 5
```

Note that `x` in practice is an object that needs to be common to all objects created from this class and I can not write e.g `x = 5` so I need a function to initialize it. So how can I call the function that initializes x only once and not for every object created? Also is it generally good practice in python to skip `x = None` and define x directly in `initializeX(cls)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the class constructor you could write an if check to see if the class attribute has been created already

```
if Test.x is None:
  # Do initialization
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't do something like this?

```py
def _new_x():
    return [1, 2, 3]  # <~~ whatever obj you need to initialize


class Test:
    x = _new_x()


instance_a = Test()
instance_b = Test()

# note they're the same:
assert instance_a.x is instance_b.x
```

Comment: I could do that but I would like the class to be able to function on each own so when I do something like this ```from classes  import Test``` I don't have to import the function as well.

Comment: You would not have to import the other function. If you imported `Test` into another module, the class would still call `_new_x` without you needing to import it.

Comment: I did not know that but still in a file with multiple classes I think it would create a mess having functions outside of them. Good to know though that I have this option might be useful in another case.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize (and set) it at the class level.

```
class Test:
    x = None  # this is a static variable common to all object created from this class
    @classmethod
    def initializeX(self, cls):
        type(cls).x = 5    # Test.x

c1 = Test()
c2 = Test()

c1.initializeX(c1)
print(c1.x)   # 5
print(c2.x)   # 5

Test.x = 10
print(c1.x)   # 10
print(c2.x)   # 10
```

Output

```
5
5
10
10
```